# AngularJS one page with multiple states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an angularjs application using angular-ui-router. There is a page that lists items, thats are filterable by name, and it shows in the url like */items?name=foo*. There is an other page, e.g. users, from where you can navigate to the items page, and those are filtered by user, like */items?userid=bar*.

I do this by having two states for the same page in *router config*:

```
.state('index.items', {
   url: '/items?:name',
   controller: 'ItemCtrl as ctrl',
   templateUrl: 'item/index.html',
   brParent: 'index.home'
})
.state('index.itemsOfUser', {
   url: '/items?:userid&:name',
   controller: 'ItemCtrl as ctrl',
   templateUrl: 'item/index.html',
   brParent: 'index.home'
})
```

I do this so clicking the items page on the navbar goes to the normal items page not the user filtered.

But when navigating to the items page from users, userid appears in the url but in $stateparams userid is undefined and I don't understand why.

I don't know if my approach is right, I am new to angular.

Comment: did you look at `state.reloadOnSearch` ? ...by the way, is not a good way share the same state among different application entities, you should not declare many states with the same url...

Comment: Well I also (tried to) ask if it is a good way to declare more than one states for the same page or with the same url, or should I search for/figure out another solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ui-router` enables retrieval of query string parameters. Your code is almost correct, just a small syntax fix:

```
.state('index.items', {
   url: '/items?name', // Remove semicolon
   controller: 'ItemCtrl as ctrl',
   templateUrl: 'item/index.html',
   brParent: 'index.home'
})
.state('index.itemsOfUser', {
   url: '/items?userid&name', // Remove semicolons
   controller: 'ItemCtrl as ctrl',
   templateUrl: 'item/index.html',
   brParent: 'index.home'
})
```

As stated in the docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters

Comment: Well its the same as before, with colons. Maybe the problem is not with the routing? If everything else is right, this shouldn't make any problems?

Comment: can you upload the controller code? let's see the `$stateparams` usage

Comment: Its something like [this](http://pastebin.com/gUnUcG21). I figured out that when the page loads with a userid, it is in the $stateparams, but after dofilter reloads, its lost.